# How to submit Data to Controller when @Html.Checkboxfor clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on mvc5. I don't know how to submit form to controller when @Html.CheckBoxFor() is clicked.
In my application I'm getting list of devices with current status like on/off.
I have created toggle switch to display on/off status. When user click on one switch need to update in Database.
how to submit the form in the toggle switch click with data class object

View like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7yRE.png)

View code:

```
@model IEnumerable<SmartPlug_Test.Models.NodeDetails>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS Includes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- JS includes -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .switch {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 60px;
            height: 34px;
        }

            .switch input {
                display: none;
            }

        .slider {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #ccc;
            transition: .4s;
        }

            .slider:before {
                position: absolute;
                content: "";
                height: 26px;
                width: 26px;
                left: 4px;
                bottom: 4px;
                background-color: white;
                transition: .4s;
            }

        input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + .slider,
        input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .slider {
            background-color: #2196F3;
        }

        input[type="checkbox"]:focus + input[type="hidden"] + .slider,
        input[type="checkbox"]:focus + .slider {
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
        }

        input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + .slider:before,
        input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .slider:before {
            transform: translateX(26px);
        }

        /* Rounded sliders */
        .slider.round {
            border-radius: 34px;
        }

            .slider.round:before {
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#status").change(function () {
                if ($("#status").is(":checked")) {
                    $("form").submit();
                }
                else {
                    $("form").submit();
                }

            });
        });
    </script>



    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Imagepath)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.status)
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.city)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nodemacaddress)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Imagepath)*@

                        <img src=@Url.Content(@item.Imagepath) style="height:50px;width:100px;" />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <label class="switch">

                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.status,@class = "form-control" })

                            <div class="slider round">
                            </div>

                        </label>

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.city)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nodemacaddress)

                    </td>
                </tr>
             }


        }

    </table>
   @ViewBag.message
</body>
</html>
```

Data Class

```
public class NodeDetails
    {

        [DisplayName("Device")]
        public string Imagepath { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Status")]
        public bool status { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("NodeMacAddress")]
        public string nodemacaddress { get; set; }
        public int switchType { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("City")]
        public string city { get; set; }
    }
```

In Controller I want like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(NodeDetails nodeDetails)
{
     //Code for db update
}
```

how to get dataclass in toggle button click ??

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the checkbox property inside form tag it will submit the form as follows:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.TestCheckbox, new { onclick = "this.form.submit();" })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I'm getting null values in controller

Comment: If you want to update list then instead of foreach loop you can use for loop otherwise for single record updation you have to use java script in which you can serialize the div and post and get it as model in controller.

Comment: I want single record to update, can you suggest one example to how we can use java script to serialize the div and post and get it as model in controller.

Comment: Please check the sample code
<div id="ii">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)

</div>
<input type="button" onclick="cc('divid')" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
In js file:
function cc(id) {
    var obj = $('#' + id+' :input').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/Index',
        data: obj
    })
}